# Generating disassembly from raw Infineon Tricore 1971 binary

Tags: ida, disassembly, assembly

Is IDA the best disassembler for a raw Tricore TC1791 (or similar) binary? I see there are several others floating around.

Which programs are going to give us the most complete ASM from a raw binary? We can get mostly what we need, but if there are better tools I will give them a go.

Comment: Yes, IDA Pro is the best. There is also a newly released tool from the NSA (yes, that NSA) called Ghidra which may support the TriCore. Where/how did you obtain your binary?

Comment: Trying to compile that now! Build process is pretty clunky.

Comment: Update. Ghidra is fantastic, a worthy contender to IDA. You need the current dev branch to get tricore support though.

Comment: I got our binary from reading it from a 2015 Mustang PCM (TC1791).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ghidra (NSA open source tool) is an excellent competitor to IDA. It is free and open source as well. I highly recommend it. The current dev branch has TC17xx and TC-29x support.

https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra

Guide to build it is here:
https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/blob/master/DevGuide.md